# Spring NPE using Annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

So I am having a problem that I know is something stupid that I am forgetting to do.  I've used Spring before but using the XML method.  But for this I have to use the annotations, the JSR 330 annotations (I have this dependency in my pom.xml).

What I have so far is:

**ExampleService.java**

```
package com.example.service.workflow;

@Named
public class ExampleService
{
    @Inject
    private StartService startService;

    ...
}
```

**StartService.java**

```
package com.example.service.workflow;

@Named
public class StartService
{
    ...
    public SvcStatus execute(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then I have this in my sprint-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.service.workflow" />
```

However, when I run my program, I am getting a NullPointerException on the startService object, when I try to call the execute() method.

It is not set in stone that I use the JSR 330 annotations.  I know that the problem is probably around my use of the @Named annotation, but I have also tried different permutations of @Component, @Service and @Controller.

Using Spring version 4.2.3.  Using modules spring-beans and spring-context, and spring-core.  I've also tried with all of the spring modules included.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: Where do you get an NPE (which field is null)?

Comment: Show us a complete example. Show us how you attempt to call `execute`. How do you retrieve the `ExampleService` bean?

Comment: I've updated my question with the relevant information.  And, yes I am calling new ExampleService(), so I guess this is probably where I am going wrong?

Comment: yes, that's it ... in order to let spring "do his work", you should call `new Something()` on any spring bean ...